# Maven surefire report's filename has redundant spaces when the tests are written using cucumber

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit

I am using maven-surefire-plugin version 2.16 along with tests written using cucumber. The .xml and .txt reports do come up fine in the sure-fire reports folder. The text within the the .xml and .txt file along with the names has a lot of extra spaces that is proportional to the number of step definitions executed cumulatively. Also the filename has a number of spaces proportional to number of steps executed. In case I run a lot of tests then the file simply does not save with the following exception

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project ******: 
Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test failed: org.apache.maven.surefire.util.NestedRuntimeException: null; 
nested exception is org.apache.maven.surefire.report.ReporterException: 
**Unable to create file for report: /Users/kgupta2/git/$$$$$$$$/target/surefire-reports/Scenario: Using $$$$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    .txt (File name too long); 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/kgupta2/git/$$$$$$$$/target/surefire-reports/Scenario: Using $$$$$$$$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     .txt (File name too long)** 
-> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Clearly the filename becomes long and I have verified that it is proportional to the number of steps executed. I am running cucumber using JUnit.

Here is my configuration for maven-surefire-plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.16</version>
<configuration>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/CucumberJunitRun.java</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I am unable to understand why these additional spaces pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. It was an issue with incorrect configuration of plugins. Since I was using JUnit to run my cucumber tests, I went ahead and removed all references of TestNG from my pom and that got it to work magically. Some references of TestNG were coming from my parent pom. Just checked that my effective pom had some dependency of testNG. Really do not have a great clue as to why this was happening. But the correct configuration fixed a bunch of other errors that were creeping in